# Generating Autoregressive x(m) Terms in R

Tags: r, time-series, simulation, autoregressive

Attempting to create code that generates x1...xm values, time series plot, and autocorrelogram given certain coefficients and white noise.

Code built so far:

```r
coeff <- c(-3,-2)
init <- c(0,1)
m <- 6
current <- init
val <- 1 + length(init)
while (val <= m) {
  val = val + 1
  current <- c(current%*%coeff, current[1:(length(current)-1)])
  print(current[1])
}
```

I know this produces x1...xm values given coefficients and initial values. Having trouble manipulating it for only coefficients and white noise to solve for example:
Xt = 2Xt-1 - Xt-2 + Wt